# Lubuntu hardware manager

Tags: hardware, lubuntu

So, I installed Lubuntu minimal and built the system from there on the 11.10 packages.

I'm wondering what package it is that includes the hardware manager I remember from Ubuntu 10.04?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for jockey ?

[image: jockey]

If so

```
sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk
```

If not , perhaps gnome-device-manager

[image: device manager]

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-device-manager
```

Comment: gnome-device-manager doesn't appear in my package list, but you are correct... jockey is what I'd been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @com.BOY Your question was answered in your link